# Consistency of processing environment members across compilation rounds

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

The Java Annotation Processing API as it stands in JDK 6 and 7 (not the apt tool API from 5) defines the lifecycle of an annotation processor. One is instantiated via the no-args constructor, the `init` method is called with a `ProcessingEnvironment` instance and then that processor is used via the `process` method. Only one instance of the processor is made and used throughout all subsequent processing rounds if applicable.

Since my processor class was getting a bit bloated, I've created handler classes for separate annotations it's supposed to deal with. In the methods of those classes I'm always passing in `Elements` and `Types` instances that I've obtained from the `ProcessingEnvironment` for their utility methods. This is making my method signatures rather long.

I'd rather just keep a reference to the `Elements` and `Types` instances in the handlers, as well as in the processor instance. I've done this by getting them from the `ProcessingEnvironment` passed into the `init` method. Now, I'm wondering if this is safe. The JavaDoc for `Processor` makes it clear that some methods are only called once for a processor, but `init` isn't mentioned here. I was kind of assuming this is implicitly understood, but I'm not 100% certain.

I'd also like to know if the `Messager` instance, which can be obtained from `ProcessingEnvironment` as well, remains the same across all processing rounds. I'd rather not have warnings/errors from one round showing up but others getting left out. I'm reasonably certain that it should be safe to use the same instances across rounds, but just would like some certainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked myself the same question and decided to always use the current round's `ProcessingEnvironment`'s utilities provided by `init`. There doesn't seem to be any difference when using *javac*, but there are other annotation processing tools which may show different behaviour. I've already experienced a few differences between the processing tool in javac and the one used by eclipse, so I handle anything not explicit in the documentation with great care. The question is, do you want test all existing processing tools?

Also, I think if those processing helper tools were meant to never change, they would be arguments of the processor's constructor.

Comment: Good points... I've wondered why they weren't just passed in through the constructor but instead had to go through some init method. Design constraints, maybe? At any rate, I'm initializing the handlers during init and give them references to the utilities, which are kept. Would be a bit of a problem if init was called more than once... I can't have the handlers replaced since they keep state across rounds. Maybe I can let init update the handler's tool refs as well. You've given me food for thought, thanks for the Eclipse warning.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth mentioning that the [AbstractProcessor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html) (which is suggested by the [javadoc of the `Process` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) as a subclass which could be used by implementors) throws `IllegalStateException` if its [`init` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html#init%28javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment%29) is called more than once.

It does not mean the passed `ProcessingEnvironment` could not return different values on subsequent getter calls or in different rounds although it would not be conventional. Anyway, it could be worth checking at the beginning of the `process` method:

```
private ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv;
private Elements elementUtils;
private Types typeUtils;

public Processor() {
}

@Override
public synchronized void init(final ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
    this.processingEnv = processingEnv;
    elementUtils = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
    typeUtils = processingEnv.getTypeUtils();
}

private void checkEnvironmentChange() {
    checkSame(elementUtils, processingEnv.getElementUtils(), "elementUtils");
    checkSame(typeUtils, processingEnv.getTypeUtils(), "typeUtils");
}

private <T> void checkSame(final T object1, final T object2, final String name) {
    if (object1 != object2) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(name + " should not change");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean process(final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, 
        final RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    checkEnvironmentChange();
    ...
}
```

Comment: That is very interesting. Only one processor per compilation, and init may only be called once in the default abstract implementation. At least that clears that question up. Maybe it's not a bad idea to check if different values are returned, as you suggested. It's been a while since I worked on this so I don't remember if it would truly be an issue or not... Depends on whether the retained objects have decent overridden equals methods or not, I guess.